# cleditor pressing and disabling button with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, cleditor

I'm trying to press and disable one of [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor) buttons in one of my textarea fields from jquery. Particullary "Show Source". I was trying to do get to button with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.textareaclass').cleditor.buttons.source.title = "Source";
});
```

But it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to personnalize the toolbar is passing parameter at the widget creation :

```
$("#input").cleditor({controls:"bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript | font size"});
```

Also, make sure not to confuse `$("#input").cleditor();` and `$.cleditor` :

The first transform an element (here #input) into a cleditor. Inside parenthesis, you can add parameters. The second is a global object which carry global and more tricky parameters (add callbacks for example).

Comment: So is it possible to get to properties of one of cleditor fields?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests you should use `$('.textareaclass').cleditor()`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: It generates same exception. Besides while creating plugins it says to use expressions like this: `$.cleditor.buttons.hello`